# Удаление после второго символа в строке (DelphiXE4)

Tags: delphi

В строках есть слова (**день**). Как используя процедуру Delete удалить все после второго слова **день**:

```
Самый лучший день сегодня день 2018. 
Не правда ли какой день хороший день сегодня день.  
день день Прекрасный.
```

Что бы получилось:

```
Самый лучший день сегодня день
Не правда ли какой день хороший день  
день день
```

Comment: функция Pos(Substr: String; Str: String): Integer
 Возвращает позицию (индекс) первого вхождения Substr в строке Str. Если Substr нет в Str, возвращает 0. функция Insert(Source: String; var S: String; Index: Integer): Integer
 Вставляет строку Source в строку S, начиная с номера символа, равного Index процедура Delete(var S: String; Index, Count: Integer)
 Удаляет из строки S подстроку, начинающуюся с номера символа, равного Index, и содержащую до Countсимволов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Точно так же, как и в предыдущем вашем вопросе, комбинируйте поиск и удаление:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

const
  s0:array[0..2] of string = ('Самый лучший день сегодня день 2018.',
      'Не правда ли какой день хороший день сегодня день.',
      'день день Прекрасный.');


var
  k,i:integer;
  s:string;

begin
  for i := 0 to High(s0) do
     begin
       s:=s0[i];
       k:=Pos('день',s);
       if k > 0 then k:=Pos('день',s,k+1)
       else Continue;
       Delete(s,k+4,Length(s)-k-3);
       Writeln(s);
     end;
  Readln;
end.
```